# How to consume Cloudant NoSQL DB service instances in mobile project

Tags: android, mobile, ibm-cloud, cloudant, ibm-mobile-services

I have created a 'Mobile App' project in bluemix here: https//console.ng.bluemix.net/developer/create-project/?env_id=ibm:yp:us-south

And while following the steps for creating the project I have added 'Cloudant Sync' as a STARTER. After creating the project I have added the two capabilities i.e. 'Authentication' and 'Data'. For Authentication I chose login from 'Google' and 'Facebook' both and for 'Data' I selected an already existing Cloudant DB instance into the project.

Then I downloaded the project and ran the project in Android Studio, here I was able to login with 'Google' account.

But, after login nothing happens. I want to get cloudant data in the android application because I have already added 'Data' (by selecting cloudant DB service) capability to the project.

I don't know how to make use of cloudant DB service in this project. 
What should I do next to get the cloudant data in this android application ?

Please refer the screenshot attached for the two things i.e. android application after login and the Mobile App that I created in bluemix.

[image: Android app after login]

[image: 'Mobile App' created on bluemix]

Comment: you may have already done this but you can see examples of how to use the cloudant sync library in your mobile app to access cloudant data  
here: https://github.com/cloudant/sync-android/blob/master/doc/CrudSamples.java 
and here: https://github.com/cloudant/sync-android/tree/master/sample/todo-sync

Comment: How is IBM MobileFirst involved here?

Answer (score 0):

There should be a button in the starter that lets you add data (as todos) to your project:
[image: starter picture]

This should connect to your Cloudant NoSQL DB service instance (when you download the project, you should have your service instance creds in the **credentials.xml**) and update when you create/delete new todos.